# How to detect when window.open fails to open a link

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, deep-linking

I am building a web app which has a list of links which deeplinks to an already installed application on the user's phone. But i want to handle a scenario whereby the application is not installed and link the user to the appstore or playstore. I am opening the links with window.open

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in [window.open documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)?

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
        var win = window.open(URL, WINDOWNAME[, WINDOWFEATURES]);
        if(win == null) { 
            isBlocked = true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        isBlocked = true;
    }
```

I will use this

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately doesn't work